# "ASP.NET Webforms MVP" as an alternative to "ASP.NET MVC"

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, webforms, mvp, design-patterns

Some days ago I discovered a "thing" which is called the **ASP.NET MVP framework** ( http://webformsmvp.com/ )

What do you think of that ? 
Is it worth to take a look on it ? 
Has anybody already experiences with that ?
I come from the "webform side" (and also from the desktop development) and really don't want to move to **ASP.NET MVC** for the next time. 
Would the **MVP pattern** a good alternative, especially for "**webform fans**"?

At my projects **RAD capabilities** are very important. My clients often want to see very soon a visual prototype. So for me classic ASP.NET webforms is the better choice.

Or should (I) we accept, that  webforms will have no future ? What are the plans of Microsoft?

Comment: Sounds a little argumentative to me. Hysteria? wtf?

Comment: What about MVC don't you like that makes you want a different framework?  You need to figure that out first.

Comment: voted to close due to the trolling nature of the question.

Comment: Seems like a reasonable question without the dig at MVC so I removed it (the dig).  Since it's asking for opinions, though, it should probably be Community Wiki.

Comment: I got right up to "MVC vs Webforms is a tradeoff between productivity and control". That is bs. They are just two different frameworks, one is the microsoft style of doing things, the other is the way everyone other then microsoft has been doing web frameworks for the last six years or so. Anyone who is familiar with web technology will probably be more productive with MVC, people who aren't will be more productive with webforms.

Comment: see https://github.com/riganti/dotvvm (production ready) and maybe https://github.com/hishamco/WebForms (not production ready) too

Comment: btw, the http://webformsmvp.com/  url you had posted seems to be broken

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is interesting, to find a balance may be important.
To many companies I've worked with, the faster the better and quality is not very important. For others, total control is necessary and MVC is a great answer.

I've been working with MVC since version 1 beta and with WebForms since .net 1.0. I must honestly say that MVC has made my life simpler when it comes to code reuse, Iterative development and flexibility. It allows me to have a faster response time, when they make last minute changes.

Having built my self a foundation (Which I also have for ASP.Net) I was able to reduce the amount of setup time for a project to almost nothing. This also gives me a good head start.

Both frameworks have their advantages and I would be curious to see what come out of MVP.

I'd like to hear from people who have gone to production with MVP.